# Use indexOf(char) and substring(int, int) to remove characters inside tags

Tags: java, tags, substring, indexof

I am trying to figure out how to write invoked method that will not print characters that are between `<` and `>` -basically between tags.

I need to use: `length()`, `indexOf(char)` and `substring(int, int)` in while loop.

Here is what I have:

```
import java.io.*; 
import java.util.*; 

public class Project { 


public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException   {
 //     final String text = "";
    final String filename = "HTML_2.txt";


    try (Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(

            System.getProperty("user.home"), "HTML_2.txt"))){ //"C:\CS210DataFiles"  

        while (input.hasNextLine()) { 
            String text = stripHtmlTags(input.nextLine());
            System.out.print(stripHtmlTags(text));
    }
    }

        public static String readFile(String filename) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("HTML_2.txt"));
    String text = "";
    while (input.hasNextLine()) {
        text += input.nextLine() + "\n";
    }
    return text;
}
public static void stripHtmlTags(String filename) throws FileNotFoundException {
    String text = readFile(filename);
    int leftTag = text.indexOf("<");
    while (leftTag >= 0) {
        String start = text.substring(0, leftTag);
        text = text.substring(leftTag, text.length());
        int rightTag = text.indexOf(">");
        text = start + text.substring(rightTag + 1, text.length());
        leftTag = text.indexOf("<");
    }
    System.out.print(text);
}

}
```

Now something is wrong with main method

Comment: can you show us sample input and expected output? Maybe a regex might help you?

Comment: Yes, please post the sample/output. I'm not sure if this project will have the input structured in such a way, but if the < and > are on two separate lines, the stripHtmlTags method would not work.

Comment: No, regex and simply replacing the words inside tags won't work for me.

Comment: @JuliaBrosseau - But still, whats the sample input and expected output?. How can people answer without I/O?

Comment: Input: <html>
 <head>
 <title>My web page</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <p>There are many pictures of my cat here,
 as well as my <b>very cool</b> blog page,
 which contains <font color="red">awesome
 stuff about my trip to Vegas.</p>


 Here's my cat now:<img src="cat.jpg">
 </body>
 </html>

Comment: Output:  My web page


 There are many pictures of my cat here,
 as well as my very cool blog page,
 which contains awesome
 stuff about my trip to Vegas.


 Here's my cat now:

Comment: @JuliaBrosseau - Will regex solution be OK?

Comment: blank lines should be printed as well for lines that had only a tag, like<html>

Comment: no, regex won't work for me as I haven't yet studied it.

Comment: @JuliaBrosseau - Hmm. Ok. Whats happening now? . Whats the problem?

Comment: the while loop is not working. I am trying to correct errors. I absolutely have to utilize length() , indexof(char), and substring(int, int).

Comment: When I use this:     static String stripHtmlTags(String html) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(html);
        int lessSign;
        while ((lessSign = sb.indexOf("<")) != -1) {
            int moreSign = sb.indexOf(">", lessSign + 1);
            sb.delete(lessSign, moreSign + 1);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
  } it works only to some point and then stops processing, however none of suggested methods gets utilized

Comment: @JuliaBrosseau - This regex might help (If you need it in the future :P) `System.out.println(s.replaceAll("(<.*?>)", "").trim().replaceAll("\\s+", " "));`

Comment: I need to not use string builder

Comment: I can't use replace all either for this problem

Comment: `stripHtmlTags` return type is `void`.  ` String html = stripHtmlTags(input.nextLine());` is wrong

Comment: hm... it returned text to me when used it with string builder

Comment: is there any other obvious mistake I can correct?

Answer (score 1):

This may help you

```
public void printExceptTag(String str) {
    StringBuffer ans= new StringBuffer();
    for(int i= 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        char ch= str.charAt(i);
        if(ch == '<') {
            i= skipInBetweenTag(str, i);
            continue;
        }
        ans.append(ch);
    }
    System.out.println(ans);
}

public int skipInBetweenTag(String str, int index) {
    while(index < str.length() && str.charAt(index) != '>') index++;
    return index;
}
```

the method  `printExceptTag(String str)` takes a string and prints the string skipping the character in between the tags.

Thank you..

Comment: You could directly use `toCharArray()` of String and then do this as well.

Comment: But I saw the OP say -  using `length(), indexOf(char) and substring(int, int) in while loop.`